# Leer multiples archivos con python y Glob

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo una carpeta con muchos archivos .json en un principio era fácil leerlos y obtener los resultados que necesitaba, pero ahora los .json tienen nombres diferentes, aleatorios con fecha y demás, en lo único que coinciden es que son extensión .json

tengo el siguiente código:

```
import json

def load_data():
    with open('windowspc_2021-04-16 11:08:00.555994_me.json') as contenido:
        resultados = json.load(contenido)
        for resultado in resultados:
            print(resultado.get('hostname'))
load_data()
```

con esto tengo el valor hostname del archivo windowspc_2021-04-16 11:08:00.555994_me.json pero hay alguna manera de hacer esa búsqueda en todos los .json algo como *.json

he leído y encontré que se puede usar una librería llamada glob pero no se como usarla en este caso o si existe otra manera de hacerlo.

agradezco su ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear una simple lista con todos aquellos ficheros que cumplan esa condición, es decir, que acaben en '.json'. Para ello solo necesitas importar el módulo os, que te permite realizar tareas con el sistema de archivos del sistema operativo.

```
import json
import os

def load_data():
    # Obtener en una lista todos los ficheros con extension json
    ficheros_json = [nombre_fich for nombre_fich in os.listdir('carpeta_donde_esten') if '.json' in nombre_fich]

    # Iterar sobre la lista
    for nombre_fichero in ficheros_json:
        with open(nombre_fichero) as contenido:
            resultados = json.load(contenido)
            for resultado in resultados:
                print(resultado.get('hostname'))
    load_data()
```

Tambien puedes utilizar esa función que indicas, glob. Esta es una función que utiliza el método de expresiones empleado en linux para un acceso más eficiente a ficheros, lo que lo convierte en una función más potente. Para este caso, quedaría muy similar a lo propuesto arriba:

```
import json
from glob import glob # Solo nos interesa la funcion, no el módulo entero

def load_data():
    # Obtener en una lista todos los ficheros con extension json
    ficheros_json = glob('carpeta_donde_esten/*.json') # '*.json' significa cualquier cosa que acabe con '.json'

    # Iterar sobre la lista
    for nombre_fichero in ficheros_json:
        with open(nombre_fichero) as contenido:
            resultados = json.load(contenido)
            for resultado in resultados:
                print(resultado.get('hostname'))
    load_data()
```

Comment: funciono perfecto, muchas gracias!

Comment: Miguel me puedes ayudar con algo mas por favor? estoy tratando de guardar el resultado o la salida en un archivo, guarde esa salida en una variable hostname_data = (resultado.get('hostname')) y trate de guardar todo en un archivo pero solo me guarda la ultima linea de lo que se imprime, se que se debe guardar todo o linea a linea pero no he podido.  Gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Por lo que indicas, lo que presupongo que pasa es que estás abriendo el fichero donde escribirás de la siguiente manera: `open(fichero, ‘w’)`. Si es de esta manera, al hacer `fichero.write()`, esta orden comienza a escribir desde el principio del fichero, sobreescribiendo lo que haya. La opción correcta sería `open(fichero,’a’)`. Con la opción ‘a’ indicas que quieres añadir al final del fichero.

Comment: Y para que todo lo que escribas en el fichero esté línea a línea, deberás añadir siempre al final de cada línea un salto de línea (‘\n’) para que así, la próxima vez que abras el fichero y se sitúe al final, se coloque en el principio de una nueva línea.